# How to get defined lines from OS X Terminal result?

Tags: macos, terminal

How do I get the first 20 lines of a OS X Terminal result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want is [head](http://ss64.com/osx/head.html)

so for a command x and the first 20 lines you enter

```
x | head -n 20
```

This runs x and pipes the input into the head command.

Answer (score 2):

If the output is from a command you are running, you can pipe the output to the `head` command.

```
$ ls -l | head -n 10
```